# element.all not able to split data in protractor testing

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

```
comparePopup() {
      element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='My Private vDiv']//label//span[1]")).getText().then(function (Data) {
          console.log(Data);
          //Data.sort();
          Data.split(' ');
      });
    }
```

While executing the code above I will get an output like below.

Actual result:

```
[ 'Dr Testing1 Hill (Testing)',
  'Dr Testing2 Hill (Testing)',
  'Dr Testing3 Hill (Testing)',
  'Mr Testing1 Hill (Testing)',
  'Mr Testing2 Hill (Testing)',
  'Mr Testing3 Hill (Testing Testing)',
  'Mr Testing Hill (Testing)',
  'Mr Testing Hill (Testing)',
  'Mr Testing Hill (Testing)',
  'Dr Testing Hill (Testing)' ]
```

I need to delete the first 3 characters of each value.

Expected result:

```
[ 'Testing1 Hill (Testing)',
  'Testing2 Hill (Testing)',
  'Testing3 Hill (Testing)',
  'Testing1 Hill (Testing)',
  'Testing2 Hill (Testing)',
  'Testing3 Hill (Testing Testing)',
  'Testing Hill (Testing)',
  'Testing Hill (Testing)',
  'Testing Hill (Testing)',
  'Testing Hill (Testing)' ]
```

**The error which I got while running protractor testing is**:

> Failed: Data.split is not a function

**I need to sort and split data.**

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one. Here the `Data` is a string array.So we need to iterate all the values to

```
    comparePopup() {
          element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='My Private vDiv']//label//span[1]")).getText().then(function (Data) {
              for(i=0;i<Data.length-1;i++){  //To iterate into the array
                 Data[i] = Data[i].subString(3);  //Now we get Testing1 Hill (Testing)
           }
          });
        }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Index signature in type 'String' only permits reading.ts(2542)

Comment: @dhrusoni Could update the implementation and the error fully.

Answer (score 0):

[`element.all`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all) returns an `ElementArrayFinder`, which is basically an array. An array has no method `split`, which is what your error says.

Instead, try

```
comparePopup() {
      element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='My Private vDiv']//label//span[1]")).map(function(elm) => {
              return elm.getText();
          })
          .then(function (texts) {
              // for each string in the array, split by whitespace,
              // discard the first word, and join the rest by whitespace
              // then sort the resultant array
              texts.map(v => v.split(' ').splice(1).join(' ')).sort();
      });
    }
```

which will output

```
[ "Testing Hill (Testing)",
  "Testing Hill (Testing)",
  "Testing Hill (Testing)",
  "Testing Hill (Testing)",
  "Testing1 Hill (Testing)",
  "Testing1 Hill (Testing)",
  "Testing2 Hill (Testing)",
  "Testing2 Hill (Testing)",
  "Testing3 Hill (Testing Testing)",
  "Testing3 Hill (Testing)" ]
```

Comment: getting error - Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: @dhrusoni I have updated the answer. The problem was `getText` returns a string, but you need an array of string.

Comment: @z11i I believe once `ElementArrayFinder` is resolved, using .then, it becomes a regular array. Also calling `getText()` on an ElementArrayFinder should not return a string as stated in your edit but an array of strings so I think your initial answer was more correct. Not sure why OP received that error. I successfully executed the below on this page `element.all(by.xpath("//ol[@class='nav-links']//li")).getText().then(function (Data) {
            Data = Data.map(eachString => eachString.split(' ')[1]);
            console.log(Data);
        });`

Comment: @z11i getting this error Property 'split' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: Are you using typescript? Does `Data` have other meaning in your code, it's not common to use capitalized variable names for parameters like this? Could you try changing `Data` to `allTxt` or something similar?